# Sort & Selecting objects while adding a lot objects quickly in FastObjectListview

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I know it is possible to sort & select multiple objects even when you are adding objects to fastobjectlistview but it's quite laggy. I am using UseCellFormatEvents & AspectGetter instead of AspectName. I tried many stuff but I didn't find any good solution yet. I am trying to add few thousand objects in 10 - 15 seconds and in same time i am selecting multiple objects/sorting them but it's not going good for me.

Comment: i am still expecting some solution. The issue is when my proxy tool keeps adding proxies to fastobjectlistview and that time if i select all proxies and try to copy it just lags. I am talking when there are 1000+ proxies in listview. There is no issue when proxies are not being added though.

Comment: try [DynamicData](https://dynamic-data.org/) - you can force the sorting and grouping to be done on background thread, so it should help with the lag